# Switch Statement with Enum - Or (||) and (&&)

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement

I'm making a project and I have a question. I have 3 enum states like this:

```
enum GameLevel
{
     Level1,
     Level2,
     None,
}
```

There's a part in my code where I want to check if there's any level selected or none, so I wanted to do something like:

```
case !GameLevel.None
```

or

```
case GameLevel.Level1 || GameLevel.Level2
```

Is This Possible?

Comment: Switch is used to map a variable to the exact values not for doing logic comparisons.  You should use if statements for that.

Comment: You could make your None equal to zero by making it the first enum, then you can just do if(gameLevel > GameLevel.None)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Various options:

Use switch with a default:

```
switch (level)
{
    case GameLevel.None:
        // Whatever
        break;
    default:
        // Do something else
        // break
}
```

Use switch with explicit cases:

```
// Note: if you add a Level3, you'd need to change this...
switch (level)
{
    case GameLevel.Level1:
    case GameLevel.Level2:
        // Whatever
        break;
}
```

Use an `if` statment:

```
if (level != GameLevel.None)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you for such a complete answer! By the way, in the second approach, if I were to add a new level 3 how would I do it? Couldn't I just follow the same approach but add more levels?

Comment: @Mykod: Yes, you could - but my point is that that switch statement is saying "level 1 or level 2" not "anything apart from none".

Answer (score 1):

Switch is not used to get a "its not the case"-case. However you can use the `default:` case, which always executes, when the other cases are "false".

For your `!GameLevel.None` better use an if case. `if(selectedGameLevel != GameLevel.None) { }`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the choice of assignment should be based on how many levels you plan on implementing. For less levels (as shown in your example), I would use if and else if as opposed to using switch. Switch only works better if there are more options, as it is then performed differently for faster execution. Jon Skeet's answer will guide you on how to implement the choice you make.